# Format MomentJS Date Output

Tags: javascript, typescript, momentjs

Trying to format a date in an application I'm working on to:

```
// Example format: YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ
// Example: 2021-09-25T00:00:00.000Z
let date: Moment;
date.format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ');
```

Formatting this date variable returns the below:

```
2021-09-25T00:00:00.000+00:00
```

How can I remove those trailing zeros after the milliseconds & the plus sign?  Essentially, everything after the plus sign including the plus like the below:

```
2021-09-25T00:00:00.000Z
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: `date.format('YYYY-MM-DD')` ?

Comment: `date.format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss')`?

Comment: @Zak - I've updated my question to reflect my inquiry more accurately.

Comment: Updated answer .. Also check out the documentation link I gave you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply remove those options ..

```
date.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Or to remove anything beyond just the plus sign ..

```
date.format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss');
```

**UPDATE**

If you want the fractional of 3 IE `.999` Then use three capital "S" - `SSS`  And lose the "Z" which is your `offset` -- `+00:00`

```
 date.format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSS')
```

The documentation can be found [HERE](https://momentjs.com/docs/)

**SCREENSHOT**

[image]

Comment: Apologies, I was not clear enough about which zeroes I'd like to remove. I've updated my question to reflect that.

Comment: If my update answered your question, feel free to accept :)